# cursor() and connection() methods are not working while trying to connect MySQL via Python(using Pycharm)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to connect MySQL database via python. I initially installed mysql-connector which did not work. later I installed mysql-connector-python and connection was successful. But when I tried to use cursor(), getting error:

Code:

```
import _mysql_connector

mydb = _mysql_connector.MySQL().connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="1234")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("show databases")
```

> Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

**

> **Solved(used alternate module: MySQLdb)**

:**

--- mysql.connector did not work for me, I used an alternate module MySQLdb which I installed using `pip3 install mysqlclient`.

code:

```
import MySQLdb
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", host="localhost", password="1234", database="mydatabase")

cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from tableName")
for i in cursor:
    print(i)

cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: is it possible that you have a typo? is it really `import _mysql_connector`?

Comment: mysql.connector did not work, I later came across https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext-module.html  and used import _mysql_connector

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect using [C Extension Module](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext-module.html). Here is basic [Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html) example:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='1234', host='localhost', database='myDatabase')

cursor = mydb.cursor()

cursor.execute('show databases')

/*
 .
 .
 .
*/

cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: mysql.connector did not work for me. I used another module MySQLdb and now the issue is resolved.